# Installing ghost CMS into AWS Elastic Beanstalk Node js app

Tags: node.js, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ghost-blog

I have a single instance linux elastic beanstalk nodejs web app mydomain.com and I want to create a /blog section running Ghost CMS.

The outcome I'm looking for is mydomain.com/blog to display content that is editable through the ghost CMS interface.

I've looked through ghost docs and poured through multiple options involving nginx reverse proxies but still no real progress.

My ideal option is to have Ghost CMS running within my nodejs application so I don't have to pay for another server. I.e. when I start the application, I start my main application on port 1337 **and** I start ghost server on port 2368 (default), then have ghost assets accessible on the /blog subdirectory.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Elastic bean stalk only provides single RUN instance. So, running 2 node js server is not possible.
If you are looking to run multiple you can try Lightsail, ofcourse then you would have to manage everything and would defeat the whole purpose of using a managed service like Elastic Bean Stalk

Comment: It's possible to get this set up working locally though, I'm not 100% on ELB infra but can you confirm that this is true knowing it is possible locally? On my local set up, I have a folder within my main app called /blog and I run 'ghost install' which essentially builds the ghost app within that folder and runs it on the new 2368 port. I can then run the main app normally on 1337 port and both are accessible

Comment: As mentioned, you can use Lightsail for your use case.